# help with scanf hex in C

Tags: c

i am trying to scan an input file with such format

r1 = 0c100009

So far I have tried this but the while loop is skipped and the output is 0.

```
    int
    read_reg (reg_t reg) {
    char r, eq;
      int i, hex;
      while (scanf("%c,%d,%[=],%x", &r, &i, &eq, &hex)==4) {
          if ((r != 'r') || (i < 1) || (i > 31) || (eq != '=')){
              error();
          }
          reg[i] = hex;
      }
      printf("%#x\n",hex);
      return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?  For instance, investigating what `scanf` returns?

Comment: Alternatively, you could read into a string and use `strtoul`.

Comment: Closed as too localized, but it's the 2nd Google result for `scanf hex`. The first is `C++` reference, not always relevant for `C` programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the `scanf` argument:

```
while(scanf("r%d = %x", &i, &hex)==2)
```

And what do you want to happen if `i` is outside limits? Should `error()` be called and what then? Probably not calling `reg[i] = hex;`.

Comment: Tried it but doesnt work. I wanted to call error() when i is outside limit, and assign hex to reg[i] if its valid.

Comment: Try `if (i < 1 || i > 31) { error(); } else { reg[i] = hex; }` to only assign when ok.

Comment: my error() contains exit(EXIT_FAILURE) so it will terminate the program. Anyway i got it already, thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 2):

Your input does not have the commas that the format string requires.  You need to remove the first comma and replace the others with blanks.

Also, the `%[=]` conversion specifier generates a string, not a single character; you need to define `char eq[2];` and remove the ampersand when passing `eq` to `scanf()`.

And, when debugging such stuff, make sure you capture the return from `scanf()` so you can report how badly things went wrong.

Note that you will be allowing considerable flexibility in the inputs even so:

```
if  ((n = scanf("%c%d %[=] %x", &r, &i, eq, &hex)) == 4)
    printf("Got: %c%d %s 0x%08X\n", r, i, eq, hex);
else
    printf("Got: n = %d\n", n);
```

The format string allows all of these lines through as valid:

```
r1 = 0c100009
r2  =  0c100009
r3=0c100009
r 4=0c100009
```

In particular, disallowing 'r 4' will be difficult with the `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me hex=0 and n=1. removed the comas and replace %[=] to %c. is that alrite?

Comment: Thank You, i figured it out already.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf() format has all kinds of requirements that your input doesn't have... try getting rid of commas and square braces.

Regarding the braces... you seem to want to make the equals sign optional, but you cannot do that in a scanf. However, you could just scan in the entire line and then pass it through a regular expression matcher.

Comment: The square brackets are not a problem; they are a valid conversion specifier which will (in this context) only accept an equals sign.

Comment: I edited my scanf inputs put still gets not correct.

Comment: Thanks i got it already.